# Calling arguments from 2 separate lists into one function

Tags: python, function, for-loop, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to calculate the alcohol by volume (abv) of some beer by using variables from 2 separate lists (which I took from a dictionary entry). I'm having trouble getting the values from both lists to be applied to the equation that I have for abv (and it's probably not possible to have a for loop with an and statement like the one I have below). Is it possible to get variables from two separate lists to be subbed into the same equation in one for loop?

Right now it's telling me that I have a type error where 'bool' object is not iterable. Here's what I've tried so far in terms of coding:

````
beers = {"SG": [1.050, 1.031, 1.077, 1.032, 1.042, 1.055, 1.019, 1.089, 1.100, 1.032], 
         "FG": [1.010, 1.001, 1.044, 1.003, 1.003, 1.013, 1.002, 1.020, 1.056, 1.000],
         "grad student 1": [5.264, 3.983, 4.101, 7.216, 2.313, 4.876, 2.255, 8.991, 5.537, 4.251],
         "grad student 2": [5.211, 3.008, 4.117, 3.843, 5.168, 5.511, 3.110, 8.903, 5.538, 4.255]}


#separating the SG and FG values from the dictionary entry
SG_val = beers["SG"]
FG_val = beers['FG']


def find_abv(SG = SG_val, FG = FG_val):
    abv_list = []
    i = 0.0
    j = 0.0
    for i in SG_val and j in FG_val:
        abv = (((1.05/0.79)*((i - j)/j))*100)
        abv_list.append(abv)
        return abv_list

find_abv()   
print(abv_list)```
````

Comment: Where does the error appear? Btw, I would recommend to make sure, that both lists have the same length and then use a range loop. After that you can simply get the elements with the index of the for loop

Comment: The error appears on the line where I start my equation - abs = (((1.05...
I'm looking to sub in the values from SG_val and FG_val into the places where i and j are in the abv equation but I'm not sure how to add two arguments at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `and` to iterate two variables in a single `for` loop. You can use the [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) function to do that:

```
def find_abv(SG = SG_val, FG = FG_val):
    abv_list = []
    i = 0.0
    j = 0.0
    for i, j in zip(SG,FG):
        abv = (((1.05/0.79)*((i - j)/j))*100)
        abv_list.append(abv)
    return abv_list

abv_list = find_abv()   
print(abv_list)
```

You also need to assign the result of `find_abv()` to a variable in order to print it, which you don't, as it seems in your code.

Another thing is that the use of `SG_val` and `FG_val` in the loop of your `find_abv` is pointless, since you have the `SG` an `FG` parameters in your function.

Comment: Thank you that clears some things up! But I'm just getting one value as a result. I was hoping to get a list of values that correspond to each of the SG and FG values in the original dictionary entry. Do you know if there's a way to do that? I tired removing the i and j variables since they didn't actually seem useful to me. 

```abv_list = []

def find_abv(SG = SG_val, FG = FG_val):
    for i, j in zip(SG_val, FG_val):
        abv = (((1.05/0.79)*((i - j)/j))*100)
        abv_list.append(abv)
        return abv_list

abv_list = find_abv()   
print(abv_list)```

Comment: It's the return statement. It should be outside the loop. Didn't notice that either. Editing my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a for loop to directly iterate through multiple lists. Currently, your function is trying to iterate through `(SG_val and j in FG_val)`, which itself is a boolean and can therefore not be iterated through.

If the two lists will always have the same number of items, then you could simply iterate through the indexes:

```
# len(SG_val) returns the length of SG_val
for i in range(len(SG_val)):
    abv = (((1.05/0.79)*((SG_val[i] - FG_val[i])/FG_val[i]))*100)
    abv_list.append(abv)
# put the return outside of the for loop so that it can finish iterating before returning the value
return abv_list
```

If the lists aren't always going to be the same length then you can write `for i in range(len(SG_val) if len(SG_val) <= len(FG_val) else len(SG_val)):` instead of `for i in range(len(SG_val)):`so that it iterates until it reaches the end of the smallest list.

Also, to output the value returned by the function you have to assign it to something and then print it or just print it directly:

```
abv_list = find_abv()
print(abv_list)
# or
print(find_abv())
```